# How to prove the set of natural numbers is closed under addition.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Seems so obvious that a natural number is closed under addition. It's just a result of how we count adding apples and apples always gives you whole numbers as adding apples is equivalent to counting the number of apples in two groups of apples . How would you mathematically prove that the set is closed under addition? It seems so obvious that it's probably taken as an axiom.

Comment: Many courses do take it as a definition.  Others derive it from other axioms.  We can't really answer this without knowing what defs and axioms you are working with.  It a very specific question to your course and there isn't a general answer.

Comment: where does this question comes from ? I think the answer is nearly pointless,  but thinking to the question isn't, as it suggests the problem of defining the integers and the proof by induction (aka the [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms))

Comment: I was about to answer a question on here asking how to prove the natural numbers does not have an upper limit. My initial reaction was that given a natural number N there exist a natural number N+1 where N+1>N as 1>0. But then I thought maybe to prove "there exist a natural number N+1" I would have to prove closure:

Comment: I think you can assume if n is natural then so is n +1 as part of the definition of real numbers.  Look up "inductive sets".

Comment: This may seem a bit flimsy but I like to first define the rationals as an ordered field (so addition is defined, closed, and associative).  Then we can define the naturals as the set containing 1 and all the numbers that are n+1 where n is a previously constructed natural.  As n +1 > n this set is infinite and induction holds.  That said, I must confess, feeling on shaky ground with this.  I think it is legit but it does feel like it's created by fiat.

Comment: I don't feel I can fix this question, how can I delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to prove something about addition, you would first have to define it. And the sum of two natural numbers, however you define it, is a natural number.

So it all boils down to how you get to define/construct the natural numbers.

Comment: There are definitions of sums of natural numbers which are not obviously natural numbers (e.g., cardinal addition).

Answer (score 3):

If you define the natural numbers as the intersection of all inductive sets and thus an inductive set, we can use induction.  n + 1 is a natural number for all natural n, and if n +m is a natural number then n+(m+1) is also natural number.  So n +m is a natural number for all n and m.